# Call a class within other class (call_user_func)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, call, classnotfound

I'm trying to create a MVC Framework for studying purposes.

So, I'm trying to call the right class and action by reading URL. But, I'm getting troubles with `call_user_func` function.

I have already read URL, and set controller and action names, but I can't call it. When I run `call_user_func` function I get the following error: `Fatal error:  Class 'PageController' not found in...`

Obviously the class is not loaded, and that's my question. How can I make it callable here?
I have a namespace for it, but I don't know if it is useful for something.

Here's the code

```
namespace Core\Dispatcher;

use Core\Routing\Router;

class Dispatch {

    private $params = [];

    public function dispatch()
    {
        $this->getParams();

        /*error occurs here*/ call_user_func(new $this->params['Controller'], $this->params['Action']);
    }

    private function getParams()
    {
        $this->params = Router::read();
    }
}
/*
 * Router::read reads url and return an array with Controller and Action names
 */
```

Yes, the whole thing is based on CakePHP Framework, but only class names, folders, etc.

So, any idea? I'm forgetting information?

Thank you

**Edit**
Here's a link to my repo on Bitbucket. I think it's enable download.
[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/cecavi/framework.git)

Comment: `the hole thing is based on CakePHP Framework, but only class names, folders` - do you use the core source code of cakePHP to make your code work? cake is quite nice for building fast MVC websites in my opinion

Comment: Is the namespace the same in the other class?

Comment: Make sure that the controller file is being included here.

Comment: No. I meant to build a basic framework from nothing to learn how to do it using cake with reference, only.

Comment: The namespace for PageController is App\Controller. But if i place it at the top, still not working.

Comment: In that line that causes the error, there are three sub-expressions, which of them causes the fault? What is the minimal code that shows the problem and how can anyone interested in reproducing the issue run it?

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt the error occurs because the class is not present in document.
To reproduce the issue you can just create a folder and set an autoloader with namespace and try to call it in another class.
I'm gonna post the entire project on Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of call_user_func is:

```
 mixed call_user_func ( callable $callback [, mixed $parameter [, mixed $... ]] )
```

param 1 is the callable

param 2..n are the parameters

So what you do here is, trying to call an object itself, with the action as parameter. That cannot work.

In order to call an object function, *callable* must be in format

```
array($object, $method)
```

So in your example:

```
call_user_func(array(new $this->params['Controller'], $this->params['Action']));
```

If your controller is in namespace App\Controller, then *$this->params['Controller']* must have the value App\Controller\ClassName.

Also, you need to include the corresponding php file with the class definition, unless you have autoloading in place.

Comment: Gone! Thank you! Just added the namespace.